# Deleting an answer by posted person is not getting deleted

Tags: support, deleted-answers

This may be asked by someone before, but I could not get the exact answer after searching.

How do I delete my answers?

The tooltip on delete says vote to delete. I think as a poster of the answer I should be able to delete whenever I wanted.

Comment: You can't delete an answer if it's been accepted. Furthermore, you probably *shouldn't* delete any (good) answer that's accumulated a lot of (up)votes.

Comment: if it is not accepted answer and if the answer is getting downvotes then?

Comment: You should be able to delete in that case. Can you link to it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343765/query-about-the-trim-method-in-java/12343818#comment16572910_12343818

Comment: Oh, you already deleted it. It's a soft-delete. It's not visible anyone other than yourself, 10k users, and moderators.

Comment: Actually, it's not deleted. Posts that are downvoted to a score of -3 or lower get slightly greyed out to emphasize the poor content. They're still visible to everyone until you actually click the delete link, then and only then are they visible to you, 10K+ users, and moderators. Deleted posts are highlighted with a red hue.

Comment: @jmort253 Check the history, the OP deleted and undeleted it several times. When I commented, it was deleted.

Comment: @Mysticial - I see now, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 4):

Just click "delete". The tooltip says "vote to delete", since it technically is a vote, but since you're the author of the answer your delete vote is binding.

The only exception is if the answer has been accepted by the question's author.

Note that posts on Stack Exchange are soft-deleted - your own deleted answers will still be visible to you and users with at least 10,000 rep (and moderators). Deleted answers have a red background, a note on them saying that they've been deleted. They cannot be voted on, and they don't affect your reputation unless they're over 60 days old and have a score of at least 3.

Comment: +1 once again thanks for your info.  But, it would have been good if there is an option to completely remove the post whenever the posted person feels.  Unless ofcourse if there is any upvotes or getting the answers as selected

Comment: You granted a license to the content when you submitted it. If you don't like that, don't post content.

Comment: @FirmView Nah, you can edit your answer to blanks if you want to hide your shame. Us 10ks do it all the time because we all see each other's deleted posts.

Comment: @Mysticial Though in some ways that's like putting up a big sign that says "LOOK AT MY REVISION HISTORY RIGHT NOW". :) Usually the fact that the post is deleted is good enough.

Comment: @AnnaLear True. So I usually accompany it with a lame excuse to add to the hilarity.

Comment: Umm, something seems wrong with that suggestion @Mysticial to edit away the answer. That's post vandalism, and I've seen users get suspended for that type of behavior. Instead, just use the delete link to delete the answer. That's all you need to do. Let's not encourage more people to abuse the system. :)

Comment: @jmort253 I meant edit away the answer *after* deleting it. 10kers usually try to do that within the first 5 min. so it doesn't get logged.

Comment: @Mysticial - In this case, it's been over 5 minutes, so we probably shouldn't encourage people to edit their answers just to clear them out. This defeats the purpose of the 10K+ and moderator ability to see deleted content, and it just makes our jobs harder. Also, who cares if you posted a bad answer and deleted it. I'm personally proud of the deleted answers I have out there with low scores. Those are those magical times when I really learned something new! :)

Comment: The comments are much more useful than the answer!

Comment: @prusswan Feel free to edit what you find most useful into the answer to make it better. ;)